# undefined method `to_i' for :offstfsal:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am getting the error undefined method `to_i' for :offstfsal:Symbol
in activeadmin. Looks like to_i has been removed. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
    index :title => "Office Expenses" do
    selectable_column
    column "Staff Salary", :offstfsal
    column "Visa & Medical", :offstvimed
    column "Total" do |total|
        :offstfsal.to_i + :offstvimed.to_i
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
column "Total" do |model|
    model.offstfsal.to_i + model.offstvimed.to_i
end
```